# No database selected, despite code testing seeming to work

Tags: java, mysql

I'm at a complete loss, I don't understand what is wrong here.  I'm writing a Java program to take a few databases and put them into a mySQL database.  I've got the JConnector in my build path:

[Build path screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj48c.png)

```
try {
                String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
                String address = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root/Exercise";
                Class.forName(driver);
                
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(address, username, password);
                System.out.println("Connection Success");
                  Statement st = con.createStatement();
                  int c =st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE test (Name VARCHAR(30))");
                  System.out.println("Table have been created.");
                  System.out.println(c+" Row(s) have been affected");
                return con;
            } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e);}
```

When I run this code, the output is:

```
Connection Success
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

When I delete the "?user=root" part of the address, it will instead give me:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
```

This implies that, if I can't connect to a database, that it'll throw the exception, so apparently it is connecting, but then it's saying no database is selected despite that I'm literally connecting to it just a few lines back.  In fact, the Statement line to the return line are code I took from another question's solution about this specific issue to test it, and their code seemed to be almost exactly the same as my own.  What in the world am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I just tried running it again without the "?user=root" because of g00se's answer, and I somehow got A DIFFERENT error message than the one I already posted that I was getting.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'exercise'
```

EDIT 2:
I just had a thought, Eclipse is on an external harddrive, and I have no idea where the SQL database is stored, but could that be the issue? They're on different drives?

Comment: Should be `String address = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Exercise";` for database called 'Exercise'

Comment: @g00se as I said in the description of the problem, when I delete the "?user=root" section of the line, it throws the error that is listed below.

Comment: The database 'Exercise' exists on the server?

Comment: @g00se When I open MySQL workbench, it's right there as the first option.  When I go into the settings, it says Hostname:127.0.0.1, port:3306. EDIT: I just had a thought, Eclipse is on an external harddrive, and I have no idea where the SQL database is stored, but could that be the issue?  They're on different drives?

Comment: The won't matter if the host on which the drive is present is the same

Comment: Then I have no idea why the hell this won't connect.  I cant even find the actual mySQL server on my computer, but apparently its there considering the Hostname is 127.0.0.1, so I have no idea.  This is driving me up a wall, there is no reason this shouldnt be working.

Comment: In fact, on MySQL workbench, when I right-click the database and click "Copy JDBC Connection String to Clipboard", this is what it copies: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root So it gives me the "?user=root" part.

Comment: Can you do raw sql, either in that workbench or with mysql in cmd.exe?

Comment: No, this is for a job and I need to enter in over 1700 lines from one database and almost 17,000 lines from the other by Monday.  Even if I was willing to do it by hand, that would be impossible to do by Monday.

Comment: That wasn't why I asked you that question ;) You *could* try url `String address = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Exercise";`

Comment: Exact same problem, that was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Raw (my)sql `show databases` says what?

Comment: It shows... nothing.  In fact, the database I had for my fiction novel is gone too.  There's nothing there.

Comment: Correction, because Im dumb and overly stressing out, i forgot the ;.  It has 4 databases:

information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
sys

Comment: Its working.  I don't know why I was missing the database or where my other database went, but that's a mystery for another day.  Thank you.

Comment: Pleasure. If you need any help with your actual task, I have some free time at the moment

Comment: Thank you for the offer but the actual task, at least so far, has been decently easy.  I just couldnt get eclipse to connect, and now knowing why, is something I will need to look into once Ive finished the actual project Im doing.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons, the exercise database (as well as others I had) went missing or were deleted.  Thank you to g00se for suggesting I look at the databases and see what was actually there, readding it fixed the problem.